# Swapping HD from one laptop to another - worked many times before, until now

Tags: hard-drive, boot, ssd, thinkpad

I am a serial ThinkPad T series user. I get a new laptop, I move my drive, and I got my new computer all setup; windows finds all the new drivers etc, and all is well.

Recently, I wanted to swap my SSD from t430 to t450, but it would not work.

The drive is recognized in t450, but the computer simply takes me to the bios boot menu asking me to choose a boot device. when I select the drive, it simply reloads, taking me back to the boot menu without any messages.

Any clues that could help me solve this?

PS - I tried it under win7, but also under win10 just now. same issue; so it seems like it is a hardware issue, not software on the drive...

Comment: Does it still work with the old machine? I was switching drives like this once and it decided to go RAW. I had to recover the files and reformat. Is it only not booting with the new laptop or does it not work with the old one as well?

Comment: @MC10 yes, it works just fine in the old machine. tried the swap twice (once under win7, another win10)

Comment: Usually Windows won't be bootable in a different hardware configuration especially if the chipset is different. You can using the Windows installation CD to run a repair install or running sysprep in the old system before you move the HDD. Whatever you choose to do make sure to backup all your important data before making any changes to the system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I get a new laptop, I move my harddrive, 
>   windows finds all the new drivers etc, and all is wel

This only works if windows is able to boot. If your new computer has a different chipset (with incompatible SATA controller) then this will fail.

Thus, do three things:

1. Compare firmware (e.g. BIOS) settings on both laptops. Are both set the AHCI?  (if the old one is but the new laptop is set to IRSST/RAID then correct this to AHCI).
2. Compare how the disk is setup. Does the old thinkpad boot from MBR, and is the new laptop setup with UEFI and expects it a system partition on GPT?
3. Failing those two. Try running sysprep to clean all old drivers, then shutdown and move the HDD to the new laptop.

Comment: # 2 was the issue - the new laptop was setup to only allow UEFI. With that turned off, all went well! Thank Hennes!